# How do I pass multiple parameters to MVC controller from jQuery $.ajax()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

This is what I doing to build the data:

```
for (var i = args.length; i < args.length; i += 2) {
    if (args.length != 0) args += ','; 
    args += '"' + arguments[i] + '":"' + arguments[i + 1] + '"';
}
```

This is how I am calling:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/blog/GetPosts",
        //data: "{" + args + "}",                    <- gives 500 in 1.6 but works in 1.3
        data: "app=blog&id=100&page=2&pagesize=10",  <- this works
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (res) {},
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {}
});
```

How to build the data with multiple parameters and pass to controller?
I need to loop and build the data since I have variable length of parameters.

Note that this works:
data: "app=blog&id=100&page=2&pagesize=10"

But I can have &abc=something in the data itself which will be treated as another parameter.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create the string representation of an object, create an object instead. Also, your loop is wrong, so it would not get the values from the array properly.

```
var data = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 2) {
  data[arguments[i]] = arguments[i + 1];
}
```

Now use the variable in the call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/blog/GetPosts",
  data: data,
  ...
```

Comment: Good job with this one. I mistyped first loop for (var i =N; i < args.length; i += 2) {} as need to exclude first N parameters. But the main problem was the string representation of params. So this is fixed now.

Comment: @Projapati: To skip the first N parameters, you would start the loop at N * 2.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass a query string into data.  If you're passing multiple values, you should pass in an object.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/blog/GetPosts",
        data: {
            app: 'blog',
            id: 100,
            page: 2
            pagesize: 10
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (res) {},
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {}
});
```

jQuery will handle the URL encoding for you.

Comment: This won't handle variable length parameters, will it?

Answer (score 1):

`data: JSON.stringify(someObject)`

Store your key/value data in an object then pass the stringified version to `data`

Comment: This doesn't work. I see 500 as well. I did data:JSON.stringyfy(args)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to make use of [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode the parameter values that have special characters such as `&`, `+` or `=`. You might also want to check out the comparison between [`escape(), encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()`](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/).

Alternatively, you might make use of [`$.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 0):

The `data: "app=blog&id=100&page=2&pagesize=10"` works  and this `//data: "{" + args + "}"` doesnt 
Because you are using "GET" as request type. to send the data along you need the request to be of type "POST" a GET request can only send the params along with the url.

Comment: This doesn't work in jQuery 1.6. I get 404. Why do you think I won't be able to do a GET with parameters?